# How to achieve this kind of look of a cube in a most efficient way?

Tags: unity, lighting, models, color

It might be a trivial question, but I couldn't come up with a simple solution.
I need to create a cube like on the image below in `Unity`.

[image]

As always, I target mobile so it would be nice if it was made on a `mobile/diffuse` shader.

I was playing with lights a little bit, but in order to achieve this kind of look, I'd need to stack multiple lights because one shadow is not enough. Also, I tried adjusting the angles of the lighting - with no luck.

Do you have any tips, how could I make one in a most efficient way?

Comment: Can you cheat with a texture? As in, just make a texture that's yellow on top and dark on the sides?

Comment: Yep! As long as it stays mobile/diffuse :)

Comment: Be more specific, ONLY a face pointing TOP should have a color? All others faces are going to be black? Or are we talking about blending these colors, accordingly to the normal of that said face?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will be giving you two answers, The one for your actuall problem,and another one with a cube that has faces colored based on how much they are facing top:

---

### To simply create a Cube like that:

- Create an image, and color it like the left half should be COLOR_X and the other half, COLOR_Y, save it; (paint will do it)
- create a cube inside blender, and go to UV/Unwrapp;
- place the face you want to be COLOR_X in the left, the others in the right;
- Export to Unity;
- Inside Unity create a simple Unlit/Texture Material;
- Set the image you created as the Texture;
- Apply the material to the UV/mapped cube;

---

### Faces should have a color depending of the normal angle;

```
    Shader "Unlit/NormalColored"
    {
        Properties
        {
            _NormalColor ("Color facing TOP", Color) = (1,.5,0,1)
        }
        SubShader
        {
            Pass
            {
                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag
                // include file that contains UnityObjectToWorldNormal helper function
                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                struct v2f {
                    // we'll output world space normal as one of regular ("texcoord") interpolators
                    half3 worldNormal : TEXCOORD0;
                    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                };

                // vertex shader: takes object space normal as input too
                v2f vert (float4 vertex : POSITION, float3 normal : NORMAL)
                {
                    v2f o;
                    o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(vertex);
                    // UnityCG.cginc file contains function to transform
                    // normal from object to world space, use that
                    o.worldNormal = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(normal);
                    return o;
                }

                float4 _NormalColor;
                float _ShadeColor;

                fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    // The Y component is TOP direction
                    float normal_y = (i.worldNormal).y/2 + .5;
                    float normal_y_2 = (i.worldNormal).y;
                    return (normal_y_2 * _NormalColor);
                }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
    }
```

- only a face pointing EXACTLY TOP should be colored, change the Frag function to this;

  ```
  fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
              {
                  // The Y component is TOP direction
                  float normal_y = (i.worldNormal).y/2 + .5;
                  if (normal_y >= .999) // THIS VALUE CAN BE SET AS A PROPERTY SO U CAN PLAY AROUND WITH IT
                      return _NormalColor;
                  return 0;
              }
  ```

Comment: I assume you know how to create a shader and then a material from this shader? If not, create one shader inside unity, then double click it, copy paste my code, then apply it to a material. It will be under Unlit/NormalColored

Comment: Btw, unlit shaders are the most performatic shaders... If this is not what you wanted, be more specific, but upvote my answer because it actually does what u described.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I want, but I need to color 5 other faces with a different one so top is color X and 5 other are color Y.

Comment: Which frag function are you using? The  "EXACTLY TOP should be colored,"?

Comment: The first one, with angles

Comment: Try the second one.

Comment: Oh, you want the face that is facing top the most to be colored?

Comment: I want one of the faces to be colored X, and other faces to be colored Y. It can be a top-face, yes.

Comment: What should happen when you rotate the cube? It looks like the problem is just a simple texture... LoL

Comment: That shader alow you to rotate the cube, and stil mantain the top-facing side be colored...

Comment: Nothing should happen :D It may be a simple texture, but I don't know how should it be created to fit the cube.

Comment: Great, follow the steps i created in the step-by-step, let me know if u get stuck in something.